# Ars magica 2 fail

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I just started using the ars magica mod on the wizard academy modpack and i did all the things right for the alter, the oculous, the compendium and the obelisk, but I acidentally used the three blue points on all three different shapes. What do I do now? I cant level up my skills and I cant make any spells 'cause they don't have any components. Can I not do any Spells now?

Answer (score 1):

[Infinity Orbs](http://am2.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Orb), Which give one point of their color, can be found in dungeons, or rarely drpped by Ars Magica guardians. Especially if you are powered up from other mods, it's possible to summon and kill them for the orb drops.